# Making a tuple of PoD from a tuple of Strong Types

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a `StrongType<>` class that enforces strong typing on PoDs:

```
template <typename T, typename TAG>
class StrongType {
private:
    std::string mName;
    T mValue;
public:
    explicit StrongType(std::string n) : mName(n), mValue() {}
    explicit StrongType(std::string n, T v)
        : mName(n), mValue(std::move(v)) {
    }

    const T &value() const { return mValue; }
    std::string name() const { return mName; }
};
```

And I have a class that keeps a tuple of `StrongType`s and needs to return a non-strong-typed tuple (indeed it should call a function with non-strong-typed arguments):

```
struct aTag {};
struct bTag {};
struct cTag {};

using aType = utils::StrongType<int, aTag>;
using bType = utils::StrongType<std::string, bTag>;
using cType = utils::StrongType<int, cTag>;

int main()
{
    aType a("a", 2);
    bType b("b", std::string {"b"});
    cType c("c", 10);

    AdvTuple<aType,bType,cType> t(a,b,c);

    //auto nt = t.getTuple();
    //std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(nt)>() << "\n";
    //std::cout << std::get<0>(nt) << "\n";

    //nt.call([](aType ra, bType rb, cType rc) {
    //});

    return 0;
}
```

This is the implementation I made, but it doesn't compile:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename ...T>
class AdvTuple {
private:
    std::tuple<T...> aTuple;
public:
    explicit AdvTuple(T... ts)
        : aTuple(std::make_tuple(ts...)) {
    }

    template <int i>
    decltype(std::get<i>(aTuple).value()) get() const {
        return std::get<i>(aTuple).value();
    }

    template <int N = 0, typename ...TA, std::enable_if<N < sizeof...(TA)> >
    auto getImpl(std::tuple<TA...> t) {
        return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(std::get<N>(t)), getImpl<N+1>(t));
    };

    template <typename ...Q>
    std::tuple<Q...> getTuple() const {
        return getImpl<0>(aTuple);
    }
};
```

This is the message from the compiler (clang on mac):

```
 In file included from
 /Users/happycactus/Documents/Progetti/Experiments/tupletraits/main.cpp:3:
 /Users/happycactus/Documents/Progetti/Experiments/tupletraits/tupletypes.h:32:16: error: no matching member function for call to 'getImpl'
        return getImpl<0>(aTuple);
               ^~~~~~~~~~

 /Users/happycactus/Documents/Progetti/Experiments/tupletraits/main.cpp:25:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'AdvTuple<utils::StrongType<int, aTag>, utils::StrongType<std::__1::basic_string<char>, bTag>, utils::StrongType<int, cTag> >::getTuple<>' requested here
    auto nt = t.getTuple();
              ^

 /Users/happycactus/Documents/Progetti/Experiments/tupletraits/tupletypes.h:26:10: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
    auto getImpl(std::tuple<TA...> t) {
         ^
 1 error generated.
```

1) How can fix it?

2) How can I implement the `call()` function with the `lambda` / `function<>` with deduced PoD types? Even non `StrongTyped` is ok.

I can use C++11 and 14.

Comment: `getTuple<Q...>` -- where is it supposed to get `Q...` from at the call site?  I'm unclear what `getTuple` is supposed to return, a tuple of copies of the `T` from the contained strongtypes?

Comment: Your use of `std::enable_if` is wrong, that non-type parameter can never be deduced. `std::enable_if_t<N < sizeof...(TA), int> = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what do you want, you need `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence`.

I mean... instead of a recursive `getImpl()`, you can use pack expansion as follows

```
  template <std::size_t ... Is>
  auto getTuple (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &) const
   { return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(aTuple).value()...); }

  auto getTuple () const
   { return getTuple(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>{}); }
```

and you can make `private` the first `getTuple()` (the one that receive the `std::index_sequence`).

Regarding `call()`, isn't clear to me what do you want. But I suppose you want a `call()` method for `AdvTuple` that receive a callable and call it with the `value()`'s.

Using again the `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence` trick, something as

```
  template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is>
  auto call (F f, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &) const
   { return f(std::get<Is>(aTuple).value()...); }

  template <typename F>
  auto call(F f) const
   { return call(f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}); }
```

with the first one that can be `private`.

The following is a full compiling C++14 example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename>
class StrongType
 {
   private:
      std::string mName;
      T mValue;

   public:
      explicit StrongType (std::string n) : mName{std::move(n)}, mValue{}
       { }

      template <typename U>
      explicit StrongType (std::string n, U v)
         : mName{std::move(n)}, mValue{std::forward<U>(v)}
       { }

      T const & value () const
       { return mValue; }

      std::string const & name () const
       { return mName; }
 };

template <typename ... Ts>
class AdvTuple
 {
   private:
      std::tuple<Ts...> aTuple;

      template <std::size_t ... Is>
      auto getTuple (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &) const
       { return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(aTuple).value()...); }

      template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is>
      auto call (F f, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &) const
       { return f(std::get<Is>(aTuple).value()...); }

   public:
      template <typename ... Us>
      explicit AdvTuple (Us && ... us)
         : aTuple{std::make_tuple(std::forward<Us>(us)...)}
       { }

      template <std::size_t i>
      auto get() const
       { return std::get<i>(aTuple).value(); }

      auto getTuple () const
       { return getTuple(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}); }

      template <typename F>
      auto call(F f) const
       { return call(f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}); }
 };

struct aTag {};
struct bTag {};
struct cTag {};

using aType = StrongType<int, aTag>;
using bType = StrongType<std::string, bTag>;
using cType = StrongType<int, cTag>;

int main ()
 {
   aType a("a", 2);
   bType b("b", std::string {"b"});
   cType c("c", 10);

   AdvTuple<aType,bType,cType> t(a,b,c);

   auto nt = t.getTuple();
   std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(nt)>() << "\n";
   std::cout << std::get<0>(nt) << "\n";

   t.call([](int, std::string, int){ std::cout << "Lambda!" << std::endl; });

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Oh Thanks, it worked like a charm and indeed it solves all my issues. Your implementation of `call(Ts...)` is exactly what I needed. I guess it can't be backported to `C++11` due to the lack of automatic return type deducing. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @HappyCactus - First of all, sorry: I've forgotten to make `const` the public `call()`; answer corrected. Second: no, the lack of automatic return type isn't a real issue back-porting the solution to C++11: you can use the `auto funcName (...) -> decltype(...)` syntax; something as `template <typename F> auto call (F f) const -> decltype(call(f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}))`; it's horrible and redundant but it's C++11 compatible. Third: the real C++11 back-porting issue are `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`, available only starting from C++14 (continue)

Comment: @HappyCactus - (continue) But isn't difficult to write a C++11 compliant substitute for they. If you want, I can add a C++11 version of my solution.